# According to Catholicism, how can the Holy Spirit proceed from the Father and the Son if it is God?

Tags: catholicism, nature-of-god, trinity, filioque

Given the Filioque (the idea that the Holy Spirit proceeds from the Father and the Son), how can the Holy Spirit be considered God? Given that God is necessary, it seems to me that the Filioque implies the Holy Spirit is contingent on the Father and the Son, but that means it’s not necessary.

Am I misunderstanding the Filioque here? Can someone provide a way to solve this apparent contradiction?

Comment: You might as well ask how the Son can be begotten of the Father if the Son is God. It's the same category of question. Your question isn't really about the Filloque (Which is about the dual nature of the procession) but rather what procession means.

Comment: @eques that’s correct. I wasn’t asking about the Filioque, rather the implications of it from a trinitarian/nature of God standpoint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**According to Catholicism, how can the Holy Spirit proceed from then Father and the Son if it is God?**

Before beginning, let us make use of Sacred Scriptures to show the Holy Spirit proceeds from the Father and the Son.

> [**How can we use Scripture to show the Holy Spirit proceeds from the Father and the Son?**](https://www.catholic.com/qa/how-can-we-use-scripture-to-show-the-holy-spirit-proceeds-from-the-father-and-the-son)
>
> One proof is that the Holy Spirit is referred to in Scripture as both the Spirit of the Father (Mt 10:20, Rom 8:10-11, 2 Cor 1:21-22, Eph 3:14-16) and as the Spirit of the Son (Rom 8:9, Gal 4:6, Phil 1:19, 1 Pt 1:11). Statements saying that the Spirit is “of” the other two Persons of the Trinity indicate that his Person is tightly bound up with and originates from them (just as the Son is the Son “of” the Father).
>
> A second proof is that the external relations of the Trinity model their internal ones. In John 14:26 the Spirit is said to proceed from the Father, but a chapter later, in 15:26, Jesus states that he will send the Spirit from the Father. The same relation is reflected in Acts 2:33, where Peter states that Jesus has received the Spirit from the Father and sends him.
>
> A philosophical explanation of this is found in the Council of Florence, which stated in 1439, “Since the Father has through generation given to the only-begotten Son everything that belongs to the Father, except being Father, the Son has also eternally from the Father, from whom he is eternally born, that the Holy Spirit proceeds from the Son” (Decree for the Greeks).
>
> The Spirit proceeds from the Father and the Son because the Father has given all things to the Son, including the procession of the Holy Spirit. For more information see the *Catechism of the Catholic Church* 246-248, 264.

The [***Catechism of the Catholic Church***](http://www.scborromeo.org/ccc/p1s2c1p2.htm) simply declares that the Church believes that the Holy Spirit proceeds from then Father and the Son, without explaining how! It does give us glimmers to help us understand the Divine Mystery. Being a Divine Mystery, it will never be fully understood while in this life. Even in heaven, the Angels and Saints will be able to contemplate this Divine Mystery for all eternity and never get bored of it.

> 246 The Latin tradition of the Creed confesses that the Spirit "proceeds from the Father and the Son (filioque)". The Council of Florence in 1438 explains: "The Holy Spirit is eternally from Father and Son; He has his nature and subsistence at once (simul) from the Father and the Son. He proceeds eternally from both as from one principle and through one spiration. . . . And, since the Father has through generation given to the only-begotten Son everything that belongs to the Father, except being Father, the Son has also eternally from the Father, from whom he is eternally born, that the Holy Spirit proceeds from the Son.”
>
> 247 The affirmation of the filioque does not appear in the Creed confessed in 381 at Constantinople. But Pope St. Leo I, following an ancient Latin and Alexandrian tradition, had already confessed it dogmatically in 447,76 even before Rome, in 451 at the Council of Chalcedon, came to recognize and receive the Symbol of 381. The use of this formula in the Creed was gradually admitted into the Latin liturgy (between the eighth and eleventh centuries). The introduction of the filioque into the Niceno-Constantinopolitan Creed by the Latin liturgy constitutes moreover, even today, a point of disagreement with the Orthodox Churches.
>
> 248 At the outset the Eastern tradition expresses the Father's character as first origin of the Spirit. By confessing the Spirit as he "who proceeds from the Father", it affirms that he comes from the Father through the Son.77 The Western tradition expresses first the consubstantial communion between Father and Son, by saying that the Spirit proceeds from the Father and the Son (filioque). It says this, "legitimately and with good reason",78 for the eternal order of the divine persons in their consubstantial communion implies that the Father, as "the principle without principle",79 is the first origin of the Spirit, but also that as Father of the only Son, he is, with the Son, the single principle from which the Holy Spirit proceeds.80 This legitimate complementarity, provided it does not become rigid, does not affect the identity of faith in the reality of the same mystery confessed.
>
> 264 "The Holy Spirit proceeds from the Father as the first principle and, by the eternal gift of this to the Son, from the communion of both the Father and the Son" (St. Augustine, De Trin. 15, 26, 47: PL 42, 1095).

[image]

[Image Source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/179870)

The great Doctor of the Church, St. Thomas Aquinas in his *Summa Theologiae*, [Question 27](https://www.newadvent.org/summa/1027.htm) and [Question 36](https://www.newadvent.org/summa/1036.htm) addresses this issue: [**Spiration**](https://icucourses.com/pages/025-08-spiration-of-the-holy-spirit).

**Question 36:**

> **Whether the Holy Ghost proceeds from the Son?**
>
> It must be said that the Holy Ghost is from the Son. For if He were not from Him, He could in no wise be personally distinguished from Him; as appears from what has been said above (I:28:3; I:30:2). For it cannot be said that the divine Persons are distinguished from each other in any absolute sense; for it would follow that there would not be one essence of the three persons: since everything that is spoken of God in an absolute sense, belongs to the unity of essence. Therefore it must be said that the divine persons are distinguished from each other only by the relations. Now the relations cannot distinguish the persons except forasmuch as they are opposite relations; which appears from the fact that the Father has two relations, by one of which He is related to the Son, and by the other to the Holy Ghost; but these are not opposite relations, and therefore they do not make two persons, but belong only to the one person of the Father. If therefore in the Son and the Holy Ghost there were two relations only, whereby each of them were related to the Father, these relations would not be opposite to each other, as neither would be the two relations whereby the Father is related to them. Hence, as the person of the Father is one, it would follow that the person of the Son and of the Holy Ghost would be one, having two relations opposed to the two relations of the Father. But this is heretical since it destroys the Faith in the Trinity. Therefore the Son and the Holy Ghost must be related to each other by opposite relations. Now there cannot be in God any relations opposed to each other, except relations of origin, as proved above (I:28:44). And opposite relations of origin are to be understood as of a "principle," and of what is "from the principle." Therefore we must conclude that it is necessary to say that either the Son is from the Holy Ghost; which no one says; or that the Holy Ghost is from the Son, as we confess.
>
> Furthermore, the order of the procession of each one agrees with this conclusion. For it was said above (I:27:4; I:28:4), that the Son proceeds by the way of the intellect as Word, and the Holy Ghost by way of the will as Love. Now love must proceed from a word. For we do not love anything unless we apprehend it by a mental conception. Hence also in this way it is manifest that the Holy Ghost proceeds from the Son.
>
> We derive a knowledge of the same truth from the very order of nature itself. For we nowhere find that several things proceed from one without order except in those which differ only by their matter; as for instance one smith produces many knives distinct from each other materially, with no order to each other; whereas in things in which there is not only a material distinction we always find that some order exists in the multitude produced. Hence also in the order of creatures produced, the beauty of the divine wisdom is displayed. So if from the one Person of the Father, two persons proceed, the Son and the Holy Ghost, there must be some order between them. Nor can any other be assigned except the order of their nature, whereby one is from the other. Therefore it cannot be said that the Son and the Holy Ghost proceed from the Father in such a way as that neither of them proceeds from the other, unless we admit in them a material distinction; which is impossible.
>
> Hence also the Greeks themselves recognize that the procession of the Holy Ghost has some order to the Son. For they grant that the Holy Ghost is the Spirit "of the Son"; and that He is from the Father "through the Son." Some of them are said also to concede that "He is from the Son"; or that "He flows from the Son," but not that He proceeds; which seems to come from ignorance or obstinacy. For a just consideration of the truth will convince anyone that the word procession is the one most commonly applied to all that denotes origin of any kind. For we use the term to describe any kind of origin; as when we say that a line proceeds from a point, a ray from the sun, a stream from a source, and likewise in everything else. Hence, granted that the Holy Ghost originates in any way from the Son, we can conclude that the Holy Ghost proceeds from the Son.
>
> **Whether the Holy Ghost proceeds from the Father through the Son?**
>
> Whenever one is said to act through another, this preposition "through" points out, in what is covered by it, some cause or principle of that act. But since action is a mean between the agent and the thing done, sometimes that which is covered by the preposition "through" is the cause of the action, as proceeding from the agent; and in that case it is the cause of why the agent acts, whether it be a final cause or a formal cause, whether it be effective or motive. It is a final cause when we say, for instance, that the artisan works through love of gain. It is a formal cause when we say that he works through his art. It is a motive cause when we say that he works through the command of another. Sometimes, however, that which is covered by this preposition "through" is the cause of the action regarded as terminated in the thing done; as, for instance, when we say, the artisan acts through the mallet, for this does not mean that the mallet is the cause why the artisan acts, but that it is the cause why the thing made proceeds from the artisan, and that it has even this effect from the artisan. This is why it is sometimes said that this preposition "through" sometimes denotes direct authority, as when we say, the king works through the bailiff; and sometimes indirect authority, as when we say, the bailiff works through the king.
>
> **Therefore, because the Son receives from the Father that the Holy Ghost proceeds from Him, it can be said that the Father spirates the Holy Ghost through the Son, or that the Holy Ghost proceeds from the Father through the Son, which has the same meaning.**
>
> **Whether the Father and the Son are one principle of the Holy Ghost?**
>
> The Father and the Son are in everything one, wherever there is no distinction between them of opposite relation. Hence since there is no relative opposition between them as the principle of the Holy Ghost it follows that the Father and the Son are one principle of the Holy Ghost.
>
> Some, however, assert that this proposition is incorrect: "The Father and the Son are one principle of the Holy Ghost," because, they declare, since the word "principle" in the singular number does not signify "person," but "property," it must be taken as an adjective; and forasmuch as an adjective cannot be modified by another adjective, it cannot properly be said that the Father and the Son are one principle of the Holy Ghost unless one be taken as an adverb, so that the meaning should be: They are one principle—that is, in one and the same way. But then it might be equally right to say that the Father is two principles of the Son and of the Holy Ghost—namely, in two ways. Therefore, we must say that, although this word "principle" signifies a property, it does so after the manner of a substantive, as do the words "father" and "son" even in things created. Hence it takes its number from the form it signifies, like other substantives. Therefore, as the Father and the Son are one God, by reason of the unity of the form that is signified by this word "God"; so they are one principle of the Holy Ghost by reason of the unity of the property that is signified in this word "principle."

Comment: So it’s a mystery?

Comment: @LukeHill ***”In Part”*** Impossible to fully comprehend.

Comment: of course, by doctrine of analogy. But it seems like you are stating that we can’t understand how a necessary thing can be reliant on another necessary thing for existence. Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: I'm not sure it's correct to say the Holy Spirit (or the Son) is "reliant" on the Father for existence. That suggests the Father causes their existence in the sense of a coming into being. They don't have independent existence in the first place. The existence of the Son is the same existence of the Father.

Answer (score -1):

According to Catholicism, how can the Holy Spirit proceed from the Father and the Son if it is God?

To illustrate this point biblically, let us read and ponder the brilliant and inspired teachings of St.Auguastine cited below.

> 264 "The Holy Spirit proceeds from the Father as the first principle and, by the eternal gift of this to the Son, from the communion of both the Father and the Son" (St. Augustine, De Trin. 15, 26, 47: PL 42, 1095).

*The Holy Spirit proceeds from the Father....*

A perfect example would be when the Father breath the Holy Spirit to Adam.

> Then the LORD God formed man from the dust of the ground and breathed the breath of life into his nostrils, and the man became a living being.-Genesis2:7

The Father breath in to Adam the Holy Spirit to give Him "Divine Life", meaning his soul was sanctified by the Holy Spirit.

In the Book of Genesis, there seems to be two creation, but it's not. God created "male and female" outside the Garden of Eden, and God chose Adam among the "male and female" and put him in the Garden of Eden, the breathing indicates, God had anointed Adam to become the High Priest of Humanity, as the Garden of Eden is the Temple of God.

Adam is worshipping the Father in the Garden of Eden.

Back to St.Augustine quote,

The Holy Spirit proceeds from the Father as seen in Genesis2:7

How about proceeds from the Son?

From the cited teachings of St.Augustine, he said,

> ..."and, by the eternal gift of this to the Son, from the communion of both the Father and the Son"

The word inspired was "eternal gift", and since the Father gave all gifts and power to Jesus Christ, he can give the Holy Spirit as He will it.

> The Great Commission
> …17When they saw Him, they worshiped Him, but some doubted. 18Then Jesus came to them and said, “All authority in heaven and on earth has been given to Me. 19Therefore go and make disciples of all nations, baptizing them in the name of the Father, and of the Son, and of the Holy Spirit..-Matthew2:17-18

We can see from the passage that people worship Jesus Christ, the same with Adam, he worshipped the Father.

And Jesus claimed, the "Father and I are one."

If one worship the Father, he also worship the Son, but can the Holy Spirit proceeds from the Son? Yes!

After the resurrection, Jesus showed us, just like when the Father breath out the Holy Spirit to santifies Adam and give him "Divine Life".

Jesus being one with the Father, also breath out the Holy Spirit to the Apostles, to bring back "Divine Life" to them, having the peace of God.

> **Jesus Appears to the Disciples**
> …21Again Jesus said to them, “Peace be with you. As the Father has sent Me, so also I am sending you.” 22When He had said this, He breathed on them and said, “Receive the Holy Spirit. 23If you forgive anyone his sins, they are forgiven; if you withhold forgiveness from anyone, it is withheld.”

The Holy Spirit proceeds from the Father and the Son, as clearly seen from this passages of Genesis2:7 and John20:22

In closing, I have one mysterious question, are these passages that talks about the Holy Spirit is the same Holy Spirit that was birthed or qanah in Proverbs8:22?

The Christian journey continues...But I already knew the answer because I know that Proverbs8:22 had finally rested and take Her rest, to the great masterpiece, God had created before the creation time begins.

Proverbs8:22 rested in the Sorrowful and Immaculate Heart of Mary and this can be seen in Proverbs9:1

The Holy Spirit , the Veni Creator had finally rested, in the Immaculate Heart of Mary, the Seat of Wisdom.

Ave!

Comment: Most of this doesn't answer the question of what procession means in regards the divine persons, especially since God breathing into Adam at his creation is not a procession in the same sense (or at all).

Comment: @eques What do you call the breathing out of the Holy Spirit from both Jesus and the Father, if not procession?

Comment: The Holy Spirit proceeds from the Father and the Son, but the act of creating Adam is not a procession of the Holy Spirit

Comment: @eques The "breathing"...got it?

Comment: The breathing? That's not a procession. Procession has a specific meaning in theology and more so it is far broader than creation. The procession of the Holy Spirit isn't the creation of Adam.

Comment: The Holy Spirit proceeds once from all eternity from the Father and the Son as Augustine and Aquinas teaches.

Comment: @equesvGod is not subject to time.

Comment: I never said He was. I said that the procession of the Holy Spirit is something eternal in contrast to the creation of Adam which is not a procession and occurs in time. Creation is also appropriated to the Father, not the Holy Spirit.

Comment: @Veni Creator Spiritus

Comment: How does that add anything? The entire premise of appropriations it that it's ascribing some aspect of the Divinity to a particular Person because it emphases some property of that Person. They are not exclusive but usual. In any case, the fact that creation is sometimes appropriated to the Holy Spirit does not mean that procession of the Holy Spirit is creation

Comment: @eques The Father breath out the Holy Spirit to sanctify Adam, to anoint Adam as High Priest of Humanity and to give him the gifts of the Holy Spirit like all the Apostles/Bishops received in the Upper Room and at their consecration. The Spirit that was breath upon is a procession, not just a mere breathing. And Jesus showed, that He can also breath out the Holy Spirit after His resurrection, to restore Divine Life, like what the Father had done to Adam, giving life to his soul.

Comment: You are conflating procession -- which occurred from all eternity -- with mission and the act of God (w/ appropriations) which unfold in time. Procession of the Holy Spirit has nothing directly to do with creation or Adam